# Desabilitar botão OnClick que carrega comentários Disqus

Tags: php, javascript, funções, onclick

Então, meu tema tem esse botão "onClick" com "comments" como título. Ele serve para clicar e carregar meus comentários do Disqus, logo abaixo a postagem. O problema é: ele dá erro diversas vezes, mostrando apenas uma área em branco muitas das vezes. Demora a carregar demais! Então eu gostaria de mostrar a seção do Disqus sem a necessidade de chamar essa função com essa botão, que a seção do Disqus carregasse normalmente logo após a minha postagem.

Aqui está o function.php do tema:

```
 if ( !function_exists( 'mvpClickCommmentButton' ) ) {
function mvpClickCommmentButton($disqus_shortname){
    global $post;
    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".comment-click-'.$post->ID.'").on("click", function(){
        $(".com-click-id-'.$post->ID.'").show();
        $(".disqus-thread-'.$post->ID.'").show();
        $(".com-but-'.$post->ID.'").hide();
      });
    });
    </script>';
}
```

e aqui o single.php:

```
<?php $disqus_id = get_option('mvp_disqus_id'); if ($disqus_id) { if (isset($disqus_id)) {  ?>

    <div id="mvp-comments-button" class="left relative mvp-com-click">
        <span class="mvp-comment-but-text">
            <?php comments_number(__( 'Comments', 'zox-news'), esc_html__('Comments', 'zox-news'), esc_html__('% Comments', 'zox-news')); ?>
        </span>
    </div><!--mvp-comments-button-->

    <?php $disqus_id2 = esc_html($disqus_id); mvp_disqus_embed($disqus_id2); ?>
    <?php } } else { ?>
    <?php $mvp_click_id = get_the_ID(); ?>

    <?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Eu tentei resolvei eu mesmo, mas eu não sei nada de PhP e Javascript, apenas html+css e um pouco da estrutura de php e javascript, paar editar coisas mínimas. Então mudei desse jeito:

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) { ?>

    <?php $disqus_id = get_option('mvp_disqus_id'); if ($disqus_id) { if (isset($disqus_id)) {  ?>

        <?php $disqus_id2 = esc_html($disqus_id); mvp_disqus_embed($disqus_id2); ?>
        <?php } } else { ?>
        <?php $mvp_click_id = get_the_ID(); ?>

        <?php comments_template(); ?>
    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Na esperança de que a seção do Disqus carregasse abaixo dos meus Posts Relacionados, sem a necessidade de clicar no botão e carregar a função, mas também não mostra nada... Só um espaço em branco:

O tema Zox News não tem a opção de desativar esse OnLick, então espero que vocês possam me ajudar com isso :) Eu tentei utilizar o código universal, mas também dá erro. Não mostra nada, e a página fica com Error 505, acredito que por conflito com essa função... Não sei.

Comment: Traduza a sua pergunta. O idioma aqui é português.

Comment: desculpa, não notei que estava no endereço PT.